# Automatically replace open quote with accented letter with PHP

Tags: php, quote

How to convert single open quote at the end of word into the right accented word, some example:

```
"Questa citta' di nome 'ROMA' e' davvero bella poiche' molto antica"
```

must become

```
"Questa città di nome 'ROMA' è davvero bella poiché molto antica"
```

Comment: You can make a simple regex that looks for single quotes after an letter and  then manipulate the matches afterwards.

Comment: Is not so simple, in this case **'ROMA'** became **'ROMÀ** and may be a word like **citta',** must mecame **città,** (note the comma)

Comment: It seems like you may need some other marker, or some way to disambiguate. For instance, how could your program know when `e'` should be `è` and when it should be `é`?

Comment: Some specific words ends with **é**, I think may be 40~50 words the others ends with **è**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### A second solution

Posting a second answer, as the other answers don't take into account whether the accent is acute or grave and other special cases as mentioned [here](http://italian.about.com/od/pronunciation/fl/italian-accent-marks.htm).

[This PHP function](https://gist.github.com/flacle/97a5baf72888d0f7b9c9?ts=2) does take diacritical mark types into account, the idea is to look at the combinations of letters and vowels for the last two characters, e.g.:

**Words that end with one vowel:**

- ...tà
- ...hé
- tè (note exception for 'tea')
- ...nì
- ...nò

**Words that end with two vowels:**

- ...ià
- ...iè
- ...iò
- ...iù

**The function does have a couple of limitations, namely:**

- Does not handle da’, the imperative form of dare
- Does not handle di’, imperative form of dire

#### Finally some remaining assumptions

- Assuming that words enclosed by start and end quotes are skipped

Perhaps the OP can elaborate on how those rules are defined in their dataset.

Comment: This approach is more accurate but don't manage uppercase accented letters

Comment: @kata32 thanks for clearing that assumption! Code has been updated, please test and let me know. There is one more assumption left from the sample sentence that you've provided, is that assumption valid?

Comment: Using another approach like this one is much better and worth looking into if anyone else has the problem of adding accent letters and not the same limitations as OP stated in the question.

Comment: Indeed, something like [this](http://www.italiantext.com/converter/) but open source :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use `preg_replace_callback` function like this:

```
$text = "Questa citta' di nome 'ROMA' e' davvero bella poiche' molto antica";

$callable = function($matches) {
    $substitution = [
        'a' => 'à',
        'e' => 'è'
    ];

    $replaced = $matches[2];
    $replaced[strlen($replaced) - 1] = $substitution[$replaced[strlen($replaced) - 1]];
    return $matches[1] . $replaced . $matches[3];
};

$result = preg_replace_callback( "/(^| )([A-Za-z]+)'( |$)/", $callable, $text);

echo $result;
```

Comment: I've some problem with accented letters, may be that preg_replace_callback don't like multibyte chars

Answer (score 0):

So you can do this with regex and capture the right characters and then just replace them with the html character coresponding to the one with accented character.

`$subject = "Questa citta' di nome 'ROMA' e' davvero bella poiche' molto antica";
$pattern = "
    /([\s]\w*)      #Captures the word with accent letter
    ([aeiouyAEIOUY])\'  #Captures the accent letter with the accent character.
    /x";
$replacement = "$1&$2acute";
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $subject);`

The output would then be

`Questa cittá di nome 'ROMA' é davvero bella poiché molto antica`

(Works now thanks to @Max regex with a little tweaking in it)

If you are looking for a better approach then using `'` as indicator as this limits to only using acute accent, you should look at @flacle answer.

Comment: A very smart approach, near to be a solution with a right use of [strtr function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php), but 'ROMA' was disappeared and I don't know why, I'm not a good regex debugger.

Comment: found the error and replaced my regex with @max regex with a few adjustments. will update my answer in a sec.

Comment: @kata32, now the code should work, it works on my system at least.

Comment: It's amazing how a single simple regex expression may solve a complicate problem like that. I must learn better regex magics.

Comment: Yep, regel is an really good thing to know, I only know a little, but it's enough to solve lots of problems with only basic knowledge. When creating regex I would recommend using this site regex101.com.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what programming language or application you have in mind, but perhaps something like PHP's string replace function will do? http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php - assuming of course that you have a finite set of replacements to do.

Comment: I don't know why the down vote, but would like to know as to why :) For such ambiguous problems either you figure out the grammar and spelling [rules](http://italian.about.com/od/pronunciation/fl/italian-accent-marks.htm) or you use a predefined dictionary/array of words.

Comment: I don't know exactly but, probably, because simple replace function obviously won't be a solution for the issue.

Comment: I initially intended it as a comment as the application was not mentioned by the OP, but unfortunately I don't have the commenting privilege yet. In any case, the [Great Dictionary of Italian](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grande_dizionario_italiano_dell%27uso) has 270.000 words,  and according to [this](http://italian.about.com/od/pronunciation/fl/italian-accent-marks.htm) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italian_orthography#Diacritics) there **are** exceptions, which can be more practically managed with a kept list.

Comment: As I  understand, the issue appears as the result of avoiding having a finite (but still huge) set of replacements.

Comment: @max I see, in that case I've posted a second solution, what do you think?

Comment: Yes, It's nice. Maybe a little complicated for the question but sill nice.

Comment: @max thanks, I think overcoming the two limitations would require a different approach, rules of languages are complex due to ambiguity :-/